# How to Set Default <a-sky> Aframe

Tags: javascript, html, virtual-reality, aframe, webvr

i saw people project using double image on a sky

```
[https://codepen.io/captDaylight/full/PNaVmR/][code]
```

when u open that you can see 2 sphere, and default background is white / without image. then if you move your cursor to sphere you can see background changed from white to image,
nah im just confuse how to set default image for white background.
i mean when i open that i can saw default image from my setting, only default image when i open that first time, other still same. can anyone help me? im really tired to tryng set default image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the src: `<a-sky src="myimg.jpg">`